# Unable to structure json file which should have multiple arrays

Tags: android, json, android-json

I want to create a json with the following requirement:

1. An array containing list of channels names.
2. Each channel name should have a subarray which should contain the list of video links for that channels.

From my android app code, I want to first show the list of channel names in a listview. Once user clicks on any listitem, I should be able to play the list of videos for that channel in sequence.

The problem for me is that, I have no experience in writing json file. So, can someone help me to suggest how to create such json file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data will be like this

```
{
    "channels": {
        "Channel1": ["link1","link2"],
        "Channel2": ["link1","link2"]
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, can you please write a small android code to parse this json to get channel names in an array and the links asociated with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create basic json content then move on to the bigger ones.You can use this [Link](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to try it for yourself  also you can use [link](http://jsonlint.com/).There are also plenty of tutorials available online.And,zappper's answer will serve your need

Answer (score 0):

Android offers pretty straight API to manage JSON.

You can use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) in conjunction with [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) to fulfill your needs.

Create first a JSONArray

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
```

Then you can create the JSONObject you need

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
```

Guess your final output would be something like this

```
JSONArray channels = new JSONArray();

JSONArray channel_one = new JSONArray();
JSONArray channel_two = new JSONArray();

JSONObject channel_one_link_one = new JSONObject();
JSONObject channel_one_link_two = new JSONObject();

channel_one_link_one.put("link", "www.   ");
channel_one_link_two.put("link", urlLinkTwo );

JSONObject channel_two_link_one = new JSONObject();

channel_two_link_one.put("link", anotherUrlVar );

channel_one.put("link_1", channel_one_link_one);
channel_one.put("link_2", channel_one_link_two);

channel_two.put("link_1", channel_two_link_one);

channels.put("channel_1", channel_one);
channels.put("channel_2", channel_two);
```

Or something like that, just to give you an usage example.

An interesting feature of JSONObject is [accumulate](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#accumulate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method.

By creating a JSONObject you can simply append values to a single mapping, effectively creating an array

```
JSONObject channel_one = new JSONObject();
String link1 = "..";
String link2 = "..";
String link3 = "..";
String link4 = "..";

channel_one.put("links", link1);
channel_one.accumulate("links", link2);
channel_one.accumulate("links", link3);
channel_one.accumulate("links", link4);
```

mapping "links" is now an array by itself.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer my question. Android part is okay for me. I was just finding how to write the json file my specific case